# How can I set a proxy in Tomcat that is different per webapp?

Tags: tomcat, proxy, web-applications

I can currently set up a proxy for Tomcat at a global level by adding -D options to catalina.bat.
However what I would like to be able to do is set a proxy for only one of the webapps and have the others not proxied.

From looking at the docs it looks like I should be able to add parameters in a context.xml file within meta-inf, but I've not yet managed to get this to work; are there any guides on this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific; its a custom web service implemented in Java.

I have other java webservices in the same tomcat instance that I don't want to use the proxy though.
Is there more info that would be helpful?

Comment: I had assumed I could do something like:

<Context>
   <Connector port="8081" proxyName="localhost" proxyPort="3128"/>  
</Context>

To branch this webapp from 8081 to 3128 if I put this into the meta-inf as context.xml (with xml declaration).

Comment: That won't work. What exactly are you trying to do? Is this for incoming connections via a reverse proxy or outgoing connections to some other service? What are you currently putting into catalina.bat (which by the way should really be going in setenv.bat so you don't have to edit the standard scripts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write the webapp so as to use `java.net.Proxy` and friends. The -D technique applies to the entire JVM.

Comment: Thanks - is there a simple example of this somewhere that you would recommend I take a look at?

Comment: @MrChris See the Javadoc for `java.net.Proxy`, the constructor `java.net.Socket(Proxy, ...)` and `java.net.URL.openConnection(Proxy)`.